# JSON library simplty dont want to let me compile it

Tags: java, json, classpath

So i wanted to use JSON library in my project but when i try to javac with a classpath of the json.jar
Used this on cmd :

```
javac -classpath json.jar main.java
```

and i get this error

```
error: package org.json does not exist
```

I dont know why ... then i made a more simple program to try and test if it runs 
i get the same error ... I am using Atom for programming in Java . 
The really simple program i tried to test :

```
import java.io.*;
import org.json.*;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
 System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the command you use to invoke the compiler?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the exact classpath you use.

Comment: Done with the edit you asked

Comment: import net.minidev.json.JSONObject instead of org.json...

Comment: @ArifAcar  main.java:2: error: package net.minidev.json does not exist
import net.minidev.json.JSONObject;

Comment: add dependency to your pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>